# Error reading characters of string . Allocate memory

Tags: c++, string, memory, null, character

i am using this codes.

Maybe it easy but now i can not. Please help me about this. I am looking always NULL in this function.

How can i solve this problem? I can not do it.

Thanks a lot.

Codes:

```
    int my_len(const char* p) {

        int c = 0;
        while (*p != '\0')
        {
            c++;
            *p++;
        }
        return c;
    }


String::String()
    :m_str(NULL)
{
}


String::String(char * other_str)
{
}
 {

    int mystrlen = my_len(m_str);
    int myrhslen = my_len(other_str.m_str);

    if (mystrlen != myrhslen)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mystrlen; i++)
        {
            if (m_str[i] != other_str.m_str[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You probably want `String::String(const char* other_str)` if only to write `String("Hello")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your non-default constructor has an empty implementation:

```
String::String(char * other_str)
{
}
```

So here `m_str` is left uninitialized.
You could maybe copy the string, if that is your intention like so:

```
String::String(char * other_str)
{
    m_str = strdup(other_str);
}
```

But then you will have to manage the memory allocated by strdup yourself, e.g. in the destructor:

```
String::~String()
{
    if (m_str != NULL)
        free(m_str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's okey. Now i am creating my_strdup function because i have to do my function always.